# AWS Lambda Layer Falha ao criar através do AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-aws

Estou tentando criar uma **AWS Lambda Layer** no **AWS CloudFormation**, mas acontece o seguinte error:

> Layer conversion failed: Some directories do not have execute permissions; (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: eff63297-bf71-4578-a665-c493a9fbdb40)

Definição do Lambda Layer no CloudFormation Template:

```
LambdaLayerTest:
      Type: 'AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion'
      Properties:
        CompatibleRuntimes: 
          - nodejs8.10
        Content:
          S3Bucket: cf-us-west-2-test
          S3Key: LambdaLayerTest.zip
        Description: Lambda Layer Test
        LayerName: lambdalayertest
```

Comment: A mesma pergunta foi respondida no [Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57204258/conversion-failed-some-directories-do-not-have-execute-permissions)